# Compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\mathcal{F}(g_{ij},f)$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

How to get the equality 1 ?

When I compute it ,I get stuck in $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}R_{ij}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\nabla_if\nabla_jf)$. I don't know how to deal the two terms.

Below picture is from 201th page of this [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ajm/1154098947).

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: Have a look perhaps at Terry Tao's blog, particularly this page:

https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/03/28/285g-lecture-1-ricci-flow/

Comment: @Malkoun I still can't compute out it, so sad

Comment: @Malkoun  where is $\nabla_i\nabla_jf$ from ?

Comment: @lanse2pty I wouldn't worry about it too much. It took mathematicians a while to understand Perelman's papers, and I did not do the calculation myself. That being said, you can find helpful formulas for how the Ricci tensor (and other geometric curvature quantities) varies when you vary the metric in Besse's book, "Einstein manifolds", towards the beginning of the book. I hope this helps. If you are still stuck, I will try to work it out myself.

Comment: to answer your second question, I think what Perelman and the authors did was write

R + |\nabla f|^2 = g^{ij}(Ric_{ij} + \nabla_i f \nabla_j f)

and then differentiated the resulting expression and used the product rule. Something like that.

Comment: @Malkoun  Thanks very much.Let me read the Besse's book first .But it's $\nabla_i\nabla_j f$, not $\nabla_i f \nabla_j f$ in the second button down. Whether there miss $f$ in above picture ?

Comment: @Malkoun  I failed,  I know $\partial_t R_{ij},\partial_t g^{ij} $ and so on ,but my result is different from the paper's.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, just use the lemma 1.5.2 in that paper. Replace, knowing that the first variation of the metric is $v_{ij} = -2 \text{Ric}_{ij}$, so that $v=-2R$, and the first variation $h$ of the function $f$ is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$, which is also $h = - \Delta f + |\nabla f|^2 -R$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know how to get $\nabla_i\nabla_jf$ in the last equality.

Comment: @lanse7pty : That $\nabla_i \nabla_j f$ are from Lemma 1.5.2. Do you mean that you dont understand the proof of Lemma 1.5.2?

Comment: Do you understand that $\delta \mathcal F$ is used as $\frac{d}{dt} \mathcal F$?

Comment: @JohnMa  I feel I'm stupid,,,I know the proof of Lemma 1.5.2 . But I think they are independent for each other. Thanks very much.

Comment: @lanse7pty I agree with John Ma. I guess it seems like you are trying to reprove the lemma 1.5.2 in that paper from scratch. If you go through the proof of lemma 1.5.2 in that paper, you will understand how this term arises. You can ask if you have issues with some steps in that proof.

Comment: @lanse7pty to be more precise, that term occurs in the proof of lemma 1.5.2 for the first time I think in the second to last line on page 200 in that paper.

Comment: @Malkoun  Yes, you are right, I go through the proof of 1.5.2 in last week ,but I am not familiar with it .So, I forget to connect it when I read 1.5.3.Thanks very much.

Comment: @lanse7pty I am glad I could help.